# For Green's function of $\Delta-c$, how to show $\int_{X}G(x,y)(\Delta-c)f(y) dy=\pm f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact Riemnnian manifold and $\Delta$ the Laplacian. Suppose that 
$G(x,y)$ be the Green's function of the elliptic operator $\Delta-c$ for a positive constant $c$. I think the following holds by twice integration by parts: 
$$
\int_{X}G(x,y)(\Delta-c)f(y) dy=\int_{X}(\Delta-c)G(x,y)f(y) dy=\int_X\delta(x,y)f(y)dy=f(x)
$$
But a paper I am reading says $\int_{X}G(x,y)(\Delta-c)f(y) dy=-f(x)$. Could anyone point out a mistake in my computation? Or Is the formula a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that $$-\Delta G(x,y) = \delta(x-y)$$